# Upgrading to windows 10 from windows 7 on a new computer

Tags: windows-7, windows-10-upgrade

Can I use my current version of Windows 7 to install Windows 10 on a new computer via the free upgrade?

I currently have a computer with Windows 7 but am planning on buying my own DIY computer soon. I don't want to have to buy a new copy of Windows but the one I currently have is an OEM edition.

I plan on moving the hard drive to the new computer, configuring it via safe mode and then initializing the update to install Windows 10 on the new computer. Will this work?

Comment: OEM Windows 7 is tied to the original hardware for life, so No, you cannot do that.

Comment: Just look for a Cheap retail windows 7 with License and install it and upgrade it on the new computer. Or pay for a windows 10 Licence you never know you may have to have bought a New Windows 10 Licence to receive the next roll out of a big windows Release in a few years.

Answer (score 0):

Sine it is a OEM windows, there may be some specific setting designed by manufacturer. so we can not move it to the new computer.
event we moved it, the windows will not be activated in the new computer.